# Does $h(1) = e$ hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ with characteristic zero and $Q$ be a quadratic form on $V$. Let $\mathcal{C}l(V,Q)$ be the associated Clifford algebra, with Clifford map $\varphi: V \to \mathcal{C}l(V,Q)$. By the universal property of Clifford algebras, if $\phi: V \to \mathcal{A}$ is another Clifford map, where $\mathcal{A}$ is an associative algebra with unit $e$, then there exists a unique homomorphism $h: \mathcal{C}l(V,Q) \to \mathcal{A}$ such that $h\circ \varphi = \phi$. Does it follow that $h(1) = e$ or not necessarily? I couldn't find an argument myself.

**Note:** By a Clifford map I mean a $\mathbb{K}$-linear map $\varphi: V \to \mathcal{F}$ where $F$ is some associative algebra with unit $1$ such that $\varphi(v)^{2} = Q(v)1$ holds for every $v \in V$.

Comment: I think homomorphisms between Clifford algebras must preserve the identity element, by definition.

Comment: @Berci the book I'm using on this subject does not specify any additional condition on homomorphisms between Clifford algebras. But maybe this property follows from the usual properties of Clifford maps. I couldn't find any argument that proves it, however.

Comment: I'm struggling to write an actual proof, but it seems like this is forced from multiplicativity. If not, I would take it as an assumption anyway.

Comment: I take it back; you can have $\phi\colon V\to Cl(V,Q)\times Cl(V,Q)$ to be $\varphi$ composed with inclusion $i$ into the first factor. Then $h$ can be taken to be $i$, and this is non-unital.

Comment: But this is also basically the worst that can happen: since $h(1)=h(1)h(1)$, we get an idempotent $e=h(1)$ and thus a decomposition $\mathcal A=e\mathcal A\times (1-e)\mathcal A$. By construction, $h$ is a unital homomorphism to $e\mathcal A$.